# Integral triangle - tikzset

Tags: tikz-styles

I would like to add a integral triangle to my tikzset. What I mean by it is shown in the image;
[image]

As you can see, it's only composed as a rectangle and a triangle. I would like for it to work as a node, the same way the others in this tikzset work;

```
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
    tmp/.style = {coordinate},
    sum/.style = {draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
    input/.style = {coordinate},
    output/.style = {coordinate},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-, thin, black}},
    transfer_func/.style= {draw, fill=white, rectangle}
}
```

Can someone help me make a style called integrator, where the input node is as shown in the picture, and the output node is the tip of the triangle. If it's of any assistanse, I made the correct shape, but have no clue on how to make it work as a node, nad or fix the output so it can be used further to create a block diagram.

```
integrator/.style = {to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(0,0.55) -- ++(0.2, 0) -- ++(0.7, -0.55) -- ++(-0.7, -0.55) -- ++(0,1.1) -- ++(0, -1.1) -- ++(-0.2, 0) -- (\tikztotarget) cycle}}
```

Comment: Welcome. I believe the closest shape that looks like that is the [`single arrow`](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.single:arrow) but it needs some customization.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                quotes,
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
INT/.style = {
    rectangle, draw, semithick, outer sep=0pt,
    minimum height=12mm, minimum width=3mm,
    append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                \draw[semithick, line cap=round]
                        (\LN.north east) -- ++ (9mm,-6mm) coordinate (\LN-out)
                                         -- (\LN.south east);
                \coordinate (\LN-in)    at (\LN.west);
                                    }% end after command
                            },% end after command
    node contents= {}
              }% end of IN T
    ]
\node (X) [INT];
%
\draw[red] (X-out) to["$\int u\,dt$"] ++ (1,0);
\draw[Straight Barb-,blue] (X-in) to ["$u(t)$" '] ++ (-1,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's an unusual solution, it contains

- the value key `integrator angle` with which you can set the triangle's angle,
- an arrow tip  `Integrator Cap` which uses aforementioned value so that it fits right around the triangle's tip and
- the `integrator` style which selects the `single arrow` shape, sets some sizes and also uses the `integrator angle`.

  This style also temporary adds the vertical line to the shape's definition. It might need adjustments for different `outer ysep` settings but that is rarely changed.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.arrows}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  integrator angle/.initial=60,
  Integrator Cap/.tip={
    Triangle Cap[cap angle=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/integrator angle}, reversed,
      sep=+0pt -.5/tan(.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/integrator angle}))]},
  integrator/.style={
    shape=single arrow, draw, minimum height=+7.5mm, minimum width=+10mm,
    single arrow tip angle=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/integrator angle},
    single arrow head extend=+0pt,
    /utils/exec=% outer seps are usually .5\pgflinewidth and are rarely changed
      \pgfutil@namedef{pgf@sh@fbg@single arrow}{% fbg is the before background path
        \pgfsetbuttcap                          % force butt cap,
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgf@sh@reanchor{single arrow}{before head}}
              {\pgfpoint{+.5\pgflinewidth}{-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep})}}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgf@sh@reanchor{single arrow}{after head}}
              {\pgfpoint{+.5\pgflinewidth}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep})}}}%
        \pgfusepathqstroke}}}        % no arrow tip, no shortening, no corners
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikz[ultra thick, >=Stealth]
  \node[integrator, draw=red, fill=blue!50]{}
    edge[<-] +(left:1)
    edge[Integrator Cap->] +(right:1.5);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]